# Django model save related model

Tags: django

I have three models, Person, Role and Student. Person is related to role with ManyToManyField and Student inherits from Person. The code:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    #fields

class Role(models.Model):
    ROLE_CHOICES = (
        ('AL', 'ALUMNO'),
        #... more choices
    )
    person = models.ManyToManyField(Person)
    role = models.CharField(
        'Rol',
        max_length = 2,
        choices = ROLE_CHOICES
    )

class Student(Person):
        # fields

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Student, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

        # what code should I put here to save role?
```

I want to, on saving a Student, automatically save a role for him/her ('AL'). Also it has to execute on create and not in update.

> I've seen other posts addresing this, but it remains unclear to me how
>   to implement this.

As I understand, I can override the `save` method, but I'm not sure how exactly do this. I'm aware that `post_save` signal can also accomplish this, but I'm not sure how either.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this before student get it's pk by save method,because m2m relations is establish by your instance pk and pk is generate after your instance save to db.
two way to archieve:

First one:

new a `signals.py` file in your app:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

from .models import *


@receiver(post_save, sender=Student)
def create_student(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    if created:
        role, is_created = Role.objects.get_or_create(name='AL')
        role.person.add(instance)
```

and in your `apps.py`

```
class UserConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'user'

    def ready(self):
        import user.signals
```

replace `User` with your own `app_label`.

Second one:

after django 1.9,django has transaction tool allow you performing actions after commit.doc is [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/transactions/#performing-actions-after-commit):

```
from django.db import transaction

class Student(Person):
    .
    .
    .
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = super(Student, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        if not self.pk:
            # do when create
            transaction.on_commit(self.update_role)
        return instance

    def update_role(self):
        # this will be call after instance save to db
        role, is_created = Role.objects.get_or_create(name='AL')
        role.person.add(self)
```

all code is untested.

Comment: Thanks it works. I'll use signals since I want to replicate it on other models that inherit from person.